# Is it possible to specify a location in a user's home directory for a shared library in VBA (in Office for Mac)?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I'm currently using the VBA code similar to the following to specify a location of a shared library for use in communicating (passing a string) from an Office application to a desktop application. The VBA code/macros will need to exist in an add-in (.ppa).

```
Private Declare Sub sharedLibPassString CDecl Lib "/Users/myUserName/Library/Application Support/myCompanyName/MySharedLib.dylib" Alias "PassString" (ByVal aString As String)
```

In code from a VBA Macro, I then can do the following.

```
Call sharedLibPassString(myString)
```

I've got the communication working, but I'd like to replace the `/Users/myUserName/` part with the current user's home directory. Normally on a Mac, you'd specify `~/Library/Application Support/...`, but the `~/` syntax doesn't work, producing a "File not found" runtime error.

I discovered that using the following Environment Variable method gets me the `~/` location that I need:

```
Environ("HOME")
```

However, I don't see a way to make this part of the `CDecl Lib` statement, since, as far as I can tell, `Environ` is evaluated at runtime.

Is there any way to specify a location of a shared library in the user's home directory (`~/`) in VBA?

---

Here are a few notes about my environment/approach:

- I'm using a Mac, though I believe if there is a solution it would be similar on a PC.
- I don't believe it shouldn't matter, but the Office application I'm using is PowerPoint (2011).
- The reason I'm trying to access an area inside of the Application Support directory, instead of the default location for shared libraries is because I'd like the Desktop application to place the shared library in a location without an installer, and without requiring a user's or administrator's privileges. If there is a better solution or location to accomplish the same task, this would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for giving a long response, I just wanted to make sure I explained this fairly well.

From this page [(Anatomy of a Declare Statement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa671659.aspx) we read that

> The Lib keyword specifies which DLL contains the function. Note that
>   the name of the DLL is contained in a **string** within the Declare
>   statement.
>   (emphasis added)

From experimentation, the VBE scolds me if I try to give anything but a string constant.

The only work around that I'm aware of requires rewriting the string constant at runtime.

Here is an example of how this could be done: Let's say your delaration statement is in Module1 in your current project, and that you deliberately wrote the declaration in this format at the top of your module:

```
Private Declare Sub sharedLibPassString CDecl Lib _
"/Users/myUserName/Library/Application Support/myCompanyName/MySharedLib.dylib" _
Alias "PassString" (ByVal aString As String)
```

You can access that module via code through this (requires permissions to VBA in trust Center listed under Developer Macro Settings):

```
Dim myModule
set myModule = ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
```

Once you've gained the CodeModule, you can replace the 2nd line directly:

```
myModule.ReplaceLine 2, Environ("HOME") & " _"
```

**Mission accomplished!**

If you do this, you will need to update the path prior to attempting to call your declared sub. There must be a break in execution that allows VBA to recognize the change. Also, you will not be able to modify the code while in break mode.

Now if I were doing this, I'd want to make sure I replace the right line, to not break code. You can check the contents of the 2nd line by calling this `myModule.Lines(2,1)` which will return the string value of the line.

However, here is a more robust solution that will find the correct line and then replace it (assumes myModule has already been defined as listed above):

```
Dim SL As Long, EL As Long, SC As Long, EC As Long
Dim Found As Boolean
SL = 1     ' Start on line 1
SC = 1     ' Start on Column 1
EL = 99999 ' Search until the 99999th line
EC = 999   ' Search until the 999th column
With myModule
    'If found, the correct line will be be placed in the variable SL
    'Broke search string into two pieces so that I won't accidentally find it.
    Found = .Find("/Users/myUserName/Library/Application Support/myCompanyName/" & _
             "MySharedLib.dylib", SL, SC, EL, EC, True, False, False)
    If Found = True Then
        'Replace the line with the line you want, second paramater should be a string of the value.
        .ReplaceLine SL, Environ("HOME") & " _"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your expertise on this, as well as your very thorough response. I was able to get this to work in the context of a presentation, but what I failed to mention is that these macros will eventually make their way to an add-in (.ppa). As far as I can tell, the line replacing doesn't work. I assume the add-in is compiled code. Do you know of a similar alternative that would work in the context of a ppa?

Comment: I've updated the original question to add the note about delivery in an add-in.

Comment: I do not have access to a Mac, and have never made a PPA... but I believe you are right about this code not working within a PPA. I think your best solution will be to assure your library is located somewhere that your program can find it. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716201(v=vs.60).aspx) is all about declaring a DLL, though it is for VB6, it is probably valid. The page indicates that if it cannot find your file, because you didn't specify the path then it will check your Path variable. Updating that to what you want would probably be a workable solution.

Comment: Thank you. Though placing the library at /usr/bin, /bin, etc.. (values found in PATH variable) continues to produce the "File not found" error at runtime, placing it at any of the default locations of the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH seems to work. Per your suggestion, I will try to continue researching ways to set environment variables from with the VBA addin. I'm not sure there is a way to do this, but if there is an alternative way to set an environment variable on any arbitrary user's machine at runtime, suggestions would be appreciated, as this is beyond my knowledge and what I can find.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Mac, so this is an incomplete answer and I don't know if it will help, but it's a couple of ideas.

I know on Windows, VB doesn't load an external library until you first try to call a function declared with it, and if you specify only the filename in the declare statement, it will use the system path to look for it. Once I did the same thing you are doing, loading a library from a dynamic path, by specifying only a filename, then making a system API call to set the current working directory to the directory of the library before loading it. Changing the PATH environment variable would probably also work.

Second idea: you could hard-code the path to a filename in the /tmp directory; then automatically copy the desired library to that location before loading it. Watch out for the file being in use by another process, but that's only an error if it is a different version of the file to the one that you want.

Comment: Thank you. For your first idea, you are correct, that the external library doesn't load until it is actually made use of. I used `ChDir` to change the working directory to the parent folder of the library, and changed the "path" of the declare statement to the name of the library file. I verified, using `CurDir` that the current directory was set to the parent folder of the library, however, when calling a function from the library, I'm greeted with "File not found: MySharedLib.dylib". Did you by chance change the working path a different way or somehow extend the library search path?

Comment: Regarding your second idea, this is essentially what my intention is, except that instead of `/tmp`, the location is within the user's Application Support directory, a place I write to often, and have guaranteed read/write access too. If I were to write to a location such as `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` on any arbitrary user's machine, would I be exposed to any potential privilege issue? Also, since it is used for temporary storage, I'd be sure to clean up when done, but is it possible that the OS would step in and remove the library from `/tmp` without my consent (while it is still needed)?

Comment: I actually didn't know about `ChDir` in VB. I used a Windows API call originally but I've just tested and `ChDir` works just as well. Come to think of it, the default path on Windows includes the current working directory but on Unix-like OSes it doesn't always, I think. In that case, setting the current directory would not help. You'd need to set the PATH variable instead. I'm afraid I don't know what OS X API call might be used for setting environment strings but it ought to work. Just to test, try putting the library in a place that's definitely on the system path first.

Comment: I think `/tmp` should be okay. Isn't it always publicly writable? The OS certainly can't remove the library while it's loaded.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, putting the library in a place that is definitely on the system path (tried /usr/bin, /bin, /usr/sbin, /sbin), with no luck. I then tried with ~/usr, which worked, as well as /usr/local/lib, /lib, and /usr/lib, which all worked. These are the defaults to the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, specified here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html I wanted to confirm this but `echo $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` returns nothing, so this is a bit confusing. Also, this is not an accessible Environment Variable from VBA.